# hide ActionBar in contextual ActionMode

Tags: android, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

How do I hide the ActionBar after starting the Contextual ActionBar?
`getActionBar()` returns null in the ActionMode.Callback methods.  Is it possible?

I only want to show the Contextual ActionBar, not both as it does now.

Comment: It shouldn't show both. The action mode (contextual action bar) overlays the action bar on the Z axis. If `getActionBar()` is returning `null`, either you do not have an action bar, or you are using `appcompat-v7`, in which case you should be calling `getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: that was it, thanks, the fragment is not appcompat-v7 but the activity was