# Hide app/action bar when copy-pasting (contextual action bar)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, copy-paste, android-appcompat, contextual-action-bar

I am making small changes to an open-source app I use called '[WaniKani for Android](https://github.com/xiprox/WaniKani-for-Android)'. When I long-press some text (in `WebReviewActivity`), the copy-paste contextual action bar appears, but the regular action bar does not hide itself (as it should, according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB)).

Here is a screenshot of the app running on my phone (JY-G4 Android 4.2.1):

[image]

I found [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220792/hide-actionbar-in-contextual-actionmode) where CommonsWare points out that an app using `appcompat-v7` (which this project does) should use `getSupportActionBar()` and not `getActionBar()`. Using a few searches, I've verified that only `getSupportActionBar()` is used in this project. All `ActionBar` and `ActionBarActivity` classes originate from

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

The gradle file specifies `appcompat-v7:+`.

I'm not very experienced with Android programming, so I'm not sure where else to look in order to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>` in your app theme